# Missing assembly reference when using class

Tags: dafny

I have the following code

```
class clazz
{
    constructor {:axiom} () requires true

    method su(x: int, y:int) returns (r: int) 
    {
       r := x + y;
    }
}

method {:main} Main() {
   var c := new clazz();
   var s := c.su(2,3);
   print(s);
}
```

How can one make use of the `clazz` class? This is the specific error:

`` error CS1061: Type `__default.ClassRoomExample' does not contain a definition for `__ctor'and no extension method `__ctor' of type `__default.ClassRoomExample' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? ``

Comment: that looks like a c# error?

Comment: Where are classes described?

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out the problem. missing a `{ }` in the constructor. Dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the Dafny compiler would complain that you have declared something without a body, in this case a constructor without a body. But you have marked your constructor with `{:axiom}`, which tells the compiler that you left out of the body intentionally. That's why the error you're seeing comes from the C# compiler, not the Dafny compiler.

The `{:axiom}` attribute, which is uncommon, was designed for body-less lemmas. If you really want to omit the code for a constructor or method, you probably want to use the `:extern` attribute instead, which lets you implement the method in another .NET language.